# Rounding a number up to the nearest multiple of a power of 2

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-2.x

I'm doing some programming challenges over at `CodeEval` and came across a pretty straight forward simple one:

> Given numbers x and n, where n is a power of 2, print out the smallest multiple of n which is greater than or equal to x. Do not use division or modulo operator.

So the input looks something like this: `13, 8` first number being `x` second number being `n`. My first instinct was to use a `while` loop and return the result of multiplying the number once the loop hits the correct result, so:

```
 8 * 0 = 0
 8 * 1 = 8
 8 * 2 = 16; break because it's greater then 13
```

My question is, is it considered bad form to use `float("inf")` instead of a set number to multiply up to?

```
import sys


def multiply(x, y):
    max_multiple_try = 0
    while max_multiple_try != float("inf"):
        res = x * max_multiple_try
        if res != x and res >= y:
            return res
        else:
            max_multiple_try += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as data:
        for line in data.readlines():
            numbers = line.rstrip().split(",")
            print(multiply(int(numbers[1]), int(numbers[0])))
```

Comment: What are the serious problems that you expect?

Comment: @NikolasRieble Well I was actually going back through my idea and I guess me saying "serious problems" doesn't make sense, since the loop ends the second the multiple is higher.

Comment: You can make an implicit float('inf') check as in my answer, if you want avoid the explicit one. Is there anything else that you want to change/improve ?

Comment: @NikolasRieble well, no not really, not yet anyways. I just didn't want to post it on SO and have someone tell me, "Go to code review for working code"

Comment: I imagine there's a clever solution that takes advantage of the fact it's a power of 2 (possibly a question for [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/)?), but given the restrictions, I'd use logarithms. Something like `trunc(n * ceil(exp(log(x) - log(n))))` ought to do it.

Comment: **This use case just *begs* for bit twiddling.**  Drop back to C.  (My advice.)  :)

Comment: @papasmurf I'm one of those recommending to go on CodeReview when applicable. I do it for the quality of the answers I usually see here, I hope it's not too often taken as a criticism by the poster :-/

Comment: Does python have a bitwise or?  If so, this is just `((x-1) OR (n-1)) + 1`

Comment: Ah, yes, I've just checked.  So `((x-1)|(n-1))+1` assuming that  `x` is positive, of course.

Comment: @Aaron Lol, no I didn't mean it like that. I just didn't wanna post in the wrong area, keep up the quality audits!

Comment: Follow up [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147430/smallest-multiple-to-the-power-of-2-plus-the-binary-difference-between-two-numb)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Function interface

First of all, it is good that you used a function to contain the code solving the problem!

However, there are some shortcomings:

- It is very confusing that the function parameter representing \$n\$ from the problem description is named `x`, and the one representing \$x\$ is named `y`.
- The function is badly named, as it doesn't multiply the two arguments. A better name would be `smallest_multiple` or similar.
- The function lacks a docstring which describes what it does. It is therefore hard to check if it is implemented correctly. The first sentence of the problem description would make a good docstring (replacing "print out" with "return").

#### Bug

The function returns the wrong result if both arguments are the same, for example:

```
>>> multiply(8, 8)
16
```

But *the smallest multiple of 8 which is greater than or equal to 8* should be 8, not 16.

(Maybe you thought that 8 is not considered a multiple of 8?)

The bug is fixed by removing the `res != x` condition.

#### Loop exit condition

Let's ignore everything that doesn't affect the `max_multiple_try` variable:

```
max_multiple_try = 0
while max_multiple_try != float("inf"):
    …
    if …:
        …
    else:
        max_multiple_try += 1
```

We can see that it is always an integer (which has unlimited size in Python). Therefore it can never be equal to the special `float('inf')` value, and the loop could as well have been written using `while True: …`.

However, as `max_multiple_try` simply counts the loop iterations, this pattern would be better written as a `for` loop using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) (and using a simpler and more descriptive name):

```
from itertools import count
…
for factor in count():  # factor = 0, 1, 2, …
    res = x * factor
    if res >= y:
        return res
```

#### Top-level code

Congratulations on using `if __name__ == '__main__'` and using `with` to open a file!

Here are some improvements:

- Iterate directly over `data` [instead of using `readlines`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246300/4621513).
- Use tuple assignment:

  ```
  x, n = line.rstrip().split(",")
  print(multiply(int(n), int(x)))
  ```

#### Alternative algorithm

The problem states that the value of \$n\$ is constrained to powers of two. While your solution actually solves the more general problem for any value of \$n\$, this description probably aims for a different algorithm which makes use of the constraint.

Hint: What does the binary representation of powers of two look like? How could you solve the problem if \$n\$ were constrained to powers of ten?

Comment: +1 for making me laugh with the bug, I caught that bug not to long ago and figured it wouldn't get caught. So thank you for that. The interface is a good valid point, I didn't really expect myself to post this, but I thought someone would have some suggestions over `float("inf")`, I like the tuple idea as well. Great answer, thank you!

Comment: very nice and complete analysis

Answer (score 2):

As someone hinted before, the 'n' is limited to powers of 2.  I'm no python expert, but I assume python ints are 64 bit and that number will be big enough not to worry about overflow.  And you certainly don't need floating point.

```
def findMultiple(maxx, powern):
    res = powern
    while res < maxx:
        res = res + powern;
    return res
```

Comment: That limits the possible factors of \$n\$ to powers of two and therefore often produces the wrong result! For example, `findMultiple(23, 8)` gives 32 = 4·8 when it should be 24 = 3·8.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Perhaps you should read the original question which explicitly states "where n is a power of 2".    Read first, call people wrong only after reading!

Comment: Yes, \$n\$ (you call it `powern`) is a power of two, but the *factors* of \$n\$ need not be. For example, given \$n = 8\$ (a power of two), your program will compare 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, etc., to `maxx`, when it should be comparing 8, 16, **24**, 32, **40**, **48**, etc.

Comment: @mkrieger Yes, you are right, sorry.   Changed answer, but untested

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid explicitly calling float('inf'), you can bypass it as follows:

```
def multiply(x, y):
    max_multiple_try = 0

    while True:       

        res = x * max_multiple_try

        if res != x and res >= y:
            return res
        else:
            max_multiple_try += 1

        if res+1 == res: ###implicit float('inf') check

            return 'not found'
```

Comment: Since `res` is an arbitrary-size integer, `res + 1` will never be equal to `res` and you could as well write `if False: return 'not found'` (or just leave it away). It has nothing to do with the `float('inf')` value.

Comment: Yet when I use float('inf') as x in multiply(x,y), then the condition hits and "not found" is returned

Comment: Alright, I understand. That means, that the check in the original question did not make any sense neither?

Comment: Well, if you pass a float value as `x` then it might actually make sense to compare `res` to `float('inf')`, but in the original code `max_multiple_try` is compared, which is definitely an integer.